# Analysis Services C#

Tags: c#, ssas

Currently we use the following lines of code to connect to our SSAS server using C#. This server only runs in multidimensional mode.

```
Server objServer = new Server();
objServer.Connect("ServerName");
```

Our new server runs in both multidimensional and tabular modes and we are getting generic errors trying to connect using the same code in this fashion.

```
Server objServer = new Server();
objServer.Connect("ServerName\Instance");
```

Connecting using the ServerName\Instance format works fine using SQL Server Management Studio but our C# code is apparently missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try escaping the `\` in `ServerName\Instance`

`objServer.Connect("ServerName\\Instance");`

or

`objServer.Connect(@"ServerName\Instance");`

Comment: Thanks! You are a genus. Figured it was something like that.